# How to securely store a password in a database while still being recoverable

Tags: database, encryption, passwords

For an application that I am working on I want to store passwords that a user enters in a way that provides some security in the event that my database is compromised but still allows an external daemon to have access to the plaintext version of the password. (It will be used for IMAP or POP logins).

What is the best way to store a password in the database so it is recoverable without the user's original password. (Not encrypted with the user's password)

I was thinking maybe public key encryption where the front end would use the public key to encrypt the password for store in the database and then the accessing daemon would decrypt the password with the private key.

EDIT:
I need the plaintext passwords so that they can be used to log on to other websevices which may not support something like OAuth

Comment: Rule #1: if you store the password in **plaintext**, or a format that can be turned back into plain text - ***it's not SAFE*** - not **EVER** - period. Don't do it. Best choice: don't store any passwords at all. Second choice: sort a well-salted irreversible hash of the password. Anything else is not safe.

Comment: I suggest reading [Everything you ever wanted to know about building a secure password reset feature](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html)

Comment: What is the most secure way that would help to limit the data that could be retrieved rather then all the passwords being out to dry. @Oded I am not trying to do a password reset, I need to passwords so that they can be used to login to a different website's authentication system

Comment: @secretformula - Fair enough, but I would say that the assumption both marc_s and I made is not a surprising one (with all the recent password thefts). Please update your question with the details from your comment so it is clear _why_ you need recoverable passwords.

Comment: If you're trying to access another site, perhaps when your users want to login to that site, they could type in their login on your site, you could compare it to your hash, and if valid you could pass the credentials on to the next site so you would never be storing the passwords.

Comment: @fdsa That would assume that they use the same password to login to my site as they do for the sites that they want to access, which could be many.

Comment: @oded, is it fair enough? It depends on whether the OP is intending to tell their users that they will be storing their plain-text passwords.

Comment: @Ben - I am not going to second guess what the OP is doing, now that he clarified. In some scenarios, one needs to use a stored password and storing it safely is a good concern to have.

Comment: The services is like a web mail, users will give me their imap or pop account passwords and then I will use them to access the data from the servers for display. There is no other way for me to login unless I have the password plaintext during login time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encrypt them, preferably with asymmetric encryption. Ideally the application (web app) encrypts them (w public key), and the daemon decrypts them (w private key), and the application and daemon and db live on different machines in different network zones.

Ideally the private key lives in a hardware security module attached to the daemon server. YubiHSM is ~ $500.

Please note that this only applies to passwords that you need to send to another party. If the password is for authenticating users with your system, then they should be hashed (and salted, and peppered).

Comment: What considerations should I take regarding the storage and use of the key?

Comment: Now that's the actual question :) It has to be in the web or database server's memory somewhere. Your options (in order of increasing ease but decreasing security) are 1) type it in when the server starts (fun!), 2) store it on a different hardened server with limited network access, or 3) store it on the web or database server in plain text but in a file that has limited access rights and is not easy to find.

Comment: Maybe it'd be better / more secure to use some asymmetric encryption algorithm like RSA or ECC instead of AES. That way you could encrypt the passwords with the public key and decrypt them on another highly secure system that contains the private key. If your webserver gets compromised all they get is the (useless) public key, while with AES they get all they need to decrypt your users passwords.